# How to use javascript to transition a property from a set attribute to a new attribute

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, transition

I am working an a project which requires a custom progress bar using only html, css, and javascript. I want to be able to set an initial condition on the progress bar and have it start at the proper place.

Example: I have a timestamp for when something started and I know when it should complete. I want the progress bar to start at the proportionally correct place and then transition the width to 100% completion over the proper time.

I am having trouble setting up the code so that this is possible. I have not yet been able to get a css transition to start at a programmatically set width.

This example shows my approach so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: "Avenir Next", sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                text-align: center;
            }
            html, body, div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: white;
            }
            #spacer {
                height: 40%;
            }
            #container {
                height: 20%;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            #progressBar {
                background-color: green;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startProgressBar()">
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startProgressBar() {

            bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");

            // assume that the bar should start at 50%
            bar.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
            bar.style.width = "50%";

            // assume that bar should complete final 50% in 10s
            bar.style.transition = "width 10s linear";
            bar.style.width = "100%";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I am new to javascript. It seems that the when I set `bar.style` the lines are not executed serially. I may just misunderstand something about how javascript works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the way you are setting the transition properties. You need to apply the animation in either a timeout or requestAnimationFrame like so:

```
function startProgressBar() {
      bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");

      // assume that the bar should start at 50%
      bar.style.width = "50%";

    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        // assume that bar should complete final 50% in 10s
        bar.style.transition = "width 10s linear";
        bar.style.width = "100%";
    });      
  }
```

Also you don't need the first set transitionDuration since you aren't transitioning to 50%, you want to start there.

Working Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3CeNFFO4JWFhB679GyAV

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

A mere `setTimeout` should do:

```js
function startProgressBar(){
  bar=document.getElementById('progressBar');
  bar.style.width='50%';
  setTimeout(function(){
    bar.style.transitionDuration='2s';
    bar.style.width='100%';
  },1);
}
startProgressBar();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:"Avenir Next", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
html, body, div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
#spacer {
    height: 40%;
}
#container {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: gray;
}
#progressBar {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="container"><div id="progressBar"></div></div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
```

Update: Whoops! didn't realize @**KevinF** had already posted a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply give #progressBar a width value in css.

```
#progressBar {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/igS0ySjiygIQVGp1OIKz